# Regex to match tokens in a string using string.gmatch

Tags: regex, lua

I need a regex to use in string.gmatch that matches sequences of alphanumeric characters and non alphanumeric characters (quotes, brackets, colons and the like) as separated, single, matches, so basically:

```
str = [[
    function test(arg1, arg2) {
        dosomething(0x12f, "String");
    }
]]

for token in str:gmatch(regex) do
    print(token)
end
```

Should print:

```
function
test
(
arg1
,
arg2
)
{
dosomething
(
0x121f
,
"
String
"
)
;
}
```

How can I achieve this? In standard regex I've found that `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\{\}\(\)\";,])` works for me but I'm not sure on how to translate this to Lua's regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local str = [[
    function test(arg1, arg2) {
        dosomething(0x12f, "String");
    }
]]

for p, w in str:gmatch"(%p?)(%w*)" do
   if p ~= "" then print(p) end
   if w ~= "" then print(w) end
end
```

Comment: What does `%p` match?

Comment: `%w` - alphanumeric, `%p` - punctuation (punctuation is all ASCII7 except alphanumeric, space and control characters)

Comment: This is really useful - I could for example add all the tokens to a table and then process them - but how could I preserve in a unique token strings delimited by the character `"`?

Comment: @user6245072 - It would be more complex program.  It should correctly handle comments, escaped quotes inside string literals, etc.

Comment: @user6245072, if handling of quoted fragments is needed, then something like this may be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664139/lua-split-string-into-words-unless-quoted/28664691#28664691

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Oh yeah comments... how do I break a string in lines?

Answer (score 1):

You need a workaround involving a temporary char that is not used in your code. E.g., use a `§` to insert it after the alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters:

```
str = str:gsub("%s*(%w+)%s*", "%1§") -- Trim chunks of 1+ alphanumeric characters and add a temp char after them
str = str:gsub("(%W)%s*", "%1§")     -- Right trim the non-alphanumeric char one by one and add the temp char after each
for token in str:gmatch("[^§]+") do  -- Match chunks of chars other than the temp char
    print(token)
end
```

See [this Lua demo](https://ideone.com/c9kTD2)

Note that `%w` in Lua is an equivalent of JS `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, as it does not match an underscore, `_`.